# Joining two csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-analysis

I have two csv files like the below. It is like a key-value pair data. If I read this into pandas data frame, it is showing like first column as "Multi-function Steering Wheel Yes". But it is actually a raw data which is not having specific columns.

```
Multi-function Steering Wheel   Yes
Power Adjustable Exterior Rear View Mirror  Yes
Touch Screen    Yes
Automatic Climate Control   Yes
Anti Lock Braking System    Yes
Alloy Wheels    Yes
Fog Lights - Front  Yes
Fog Lights - Rear   Yes
.................

Engine Type T-Jet Petrol Engine
Engine Description  1.4-litre 123.2bhp 16V T-Jet Petrol Engine
Engine Displacement(cc) 1368
No. of cylinder 4
Maximum Power   123.2bhp@5000rpm
Maximum Torque  208Nm@2000-3500rpm
Valves Per Cylinder 4
Valve Configuration DOHC
Fuel Supply System  MPFI
Bore x Stroke   No
Compression Ratio   No
...........
...........
```

If I join these two tables, I need to get the below table.

```
Multi-function Steering Wheel   Yes
Power Adjustable Exterior Rear View Mirror  Yes
Touch Screen    Yes
Automatic Climate Control   Yes
Anti Lock Braking System    Yes
Alloy Wheels    Yes
Fog Lights - Front  Yes
Fog Lights - Rear   Yes
Engine Type T-Jet Petrol Engine
Engine Description  1.4-litre 123.2bhp 16V T-Jet Petrol Engine
Engine Displacement(cc) 1368
No. of cylinder 4
Maximum Power   123.2bhp@5000rpm
Maximum Torque  208Nm@2000-3500rpm
Valves Per Cylinder 4
Valve Configuration DOHC
Fuel Supply System  MPFI
Bore x Stroke   No
Compression Ratio   No
```

I have more than 10 csv files in the same way. I need to add these 10 files in a single sheet like above format. I tried with concatenation, but it is not getting what I expected. 
Can anyone explain how to do it in pandas. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Columns in CSV (comma-separated values) format text must be separated by commas(`,`), not white spaces. Unless there are any valid delimiters(commas), Pandas will recognize the whole line as one single column.

You may use `re` (regex) module to replace those white spaces to commas to make proper CSV text.

```py
import re
text = """Multi-function Steering Wheel   Yes
Power Adjustable Exterior Rear View Mirror  Yes
Engine Description  1.4-litre 123.2bhp 16V T-Jet Petrol Engine
Engine Displacement(cc) 1368
No. of cylinder 4
Maximum Power   123.2bhp@5000rpm
... ...
"""

# Replaces last white space(s) in each line into comma
p = re.compile(r' +(?=[^ ]+$)', re.MULTILINE)
replaced = re.sub(p, ',', text)
print(replaced)
```

This will give you an output like

```
Multi-function Steering Wheel,Yes
Power Adjustable Exterior Rear View Mirror,Yes
Engine Description  1.4-litre 123.2bhp 16V T-Jet Petrol,Engine
Engine Displacement(cc),1368
No. of cylinder,4
Maximum Power,123.2bhp@5000rpm
...,...
```

Note that if you intend to divide the line like `Engine Description  1.4-litre 123.2bhp 16V T-Jet Petrol Engine` into `Engine Description,1.4-litre 123.2bhp 16V T-Jet Petrol Engines`, those lines should be edited by hand because the above code will just mechanically replace *last* white spaces in each line.

Instead of using python, you can just use text editors like VSCode (See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-and-replace)